# Percentage Difference Between Two Temp Columns in SQL

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to add a column to this query that will calculate the percentage difference between c.PopulationForecast and c.PopulationActualMAX and/or c.PopulationActualMin. It would be nice if it was just one column but I will settle for two.

```
SELECT c.DepartmentName, c.DateandTime, c.ExecutionDate, c.PopulationForecast, c.PopulationActualMAX, c.PopulationActualMIN 
FROM 
    (SELECT DepartmentName, DateandTime, ExecutionDate FROM ForecastTable WHERE DateandTime >= CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)) d
CROSS APPLY
    (SELECT *,
        (SELECT MAX(ACT.PopulationActual) FROM ActualsTable ACT JOIN DepartmentTable DTD ON DTD.DepartmentTypeID = ACT.DepartmentTypeId JOIN FacilityTable FD ON FD.FacilityID = ACT.FacilityID WHERE (ACT.TargetDateTime >= DATEADD(DAY, -28, d.DateandTime)) and (DATEPART(WEEKDAY, ACT.TargetDateTime) = DATEPART(WEEKDAY, d.DateandTime)) and (CONCAT(FD.FacilityKey,'.All',DTD.DepartmentTypeKey) = DepartmentName))
        as PopulationActualMAX,
        (SELECT MIN(ACT.PopulationActual) FROM ActualsTable ACT JOIN DepartmentTable DTD ON DTD.DepartmentTypeID = ACT.DepartmentTypeId JOIN FacilityTable FD ON FD.FacilityID = ACT.FacilityID WHERE (ACT.TargetDateTime >= DATEADD(DAY, -28, d.DateandTime)) and (DATEPART(WEEKDAY, ACT.TargetDateTime) = DATEPART(WEEKDAY, d.DateandTime)) and (CONCAT(FD.FacilityKey,'.All',DTD.DepartmentTypeKey) = DepartmentName))
        as PopulationActualMIN      
     FROM ForecastTable
     WHERE 
        DepartmentName = d.DepartmentName
        and DateandTime = d.DateandTime
        and (
            (ROUND (PopulationForecast, 0) > 
                (
                SELECT MAX(ACT.PopulationActual) 
                FROM ActualsTable ACT 
                JOIN DepartmentTable DTD ON DTD.DepartmentTypeID = ACT.DepartmentTypeId 
                JOIN FacilityTable FD ON FD.FacilityID = ACT.FacilityID 
                WHERE (ACT.TargetDateTime >= DATEADD(DAY, -28, d.DateandTime)) 
                and (DATEPART(WEEKDAY, ACT.TargetDateTime) = DATEPART(WEEKDAY, d.DateandTime)) 
                and (CONCAT(FD.FacilityKey,'.All',DTD.DepartmentTypeKey) = d.DepartmentName)
                )
            ) 
            or 
            (ROUND (PopulationForecast, 0) < 
                (
                SELECT MIN(ACT.PopulationActual) 
                FROM ActualsTable ACT 
                JOIN DepartmentTable DTD ON DTD.DepartmentTypeID = ACT.DepartmentTypeId 
                JOIN FacilityTable FD ON FD.FacilityID = ACT.FacilityID 
                WHERE (ACT.TargetDateTime >= DATEADD(DAY, -28, d.DateandTime))
                and (DATEPART(WEEKDAY, ACT.TargetDateTime) = DATEPART(WEEKDAY, d.DateandTime))
                and (CONCAT(FD.FacilityKey,'.All',DTD.DepartmentTypeKey) = d.DepartmentName)
                )
            )
            )
        ) c
    Order By d.DepartmentName, d.DateandTime
```

Comment: So what is the problem?   Show us db schema, sample data, current and expected output. 
 Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

 [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

 Try create a sample in http://rextester.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there anything stopping you putting the difference in your outer select (first line)?

For example:

```
(c.PopulationForecast-c.PopulationActualMIN)/c.PopulationForecast ForecastVsMin
, (c.PopulationForecast-c.PopulationActualMAX)/c.PopulationForecast ForecastVsMax
```

From your query it looks like you already have all three fields you're looking for.

Comment: Then there's a line where the population forecast is zero. What's your expected result in that situation?